# Install PyMuPDF

Tags: python, installation, pip, pymupdf

I was installing requirements, where the error popped up

> ERROR: Failed to build wheels for PyMuPDF, which is required to install projects based on pyproject.toml

I tried to install the PyMuPDF with python setup.py install, but then:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "setup.py", line 706, in <module> subprocess.run( command, shell=True, check=True) File "C:\Users\we\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 438, in run output=stdout, stderr=stderr) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd mupdf-1.22.0-source&&"devenv.com" >platform/win32/mupdf.sln /Build "ReleaseTesseract|x64"/Project mupdf' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

I used "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" and "python -m pip install --upgrade pymupdf". but after "python -m pip install --upgrade pymupdf" i got:

`Running setup.py clean for pymupdf Failed to build pymupdf Installing collected packages: pymupdf Running setup.py install for pymupdf error`

What should I do?
pip 23.1.2 from C:\Users\we\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.11)

I found the same problem: https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/1955
But it doesn't help

Comment: Cann you [edit] and insert the complete error message that you get? Please use Block code formatting, i.e. wrap your error message in three '

Comment: Please open an issue on the Github home page of PyMuPDF, https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF. Doesn't make much sense to discuss it here. You can however make sure that you adhere to all prerequisites for source installation on Windows, like Visual Studio is installed, etc.